# O que significa uma variável conter um valor?

Tags: java, c, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

*Havendo diferença entre as linguagens ou entre tipos de variáveis, estou perguntando para um caso simples,  envolvendo variáveis inteiras em C (por exemplo, de tipo `int`). Se quiser falar no contexto do Java com seus tipos primitivos, também interessa.*

---

O que significa uma variável conter um valor?

No código fazemos `int x = 2;` (ou,  mais precisamente,  declaramos `int x;` e atribuímos `x = 2;`), porém a variável em si não é o que ela vale. Ou é?

Para quem tem uma noção incompleta de como funciona debaixo dos panos isso faz uma confusão danada na cabeça.

Tentando elaborar: a variável desaparece no código compilado. E se variável já é uma indireção, juntando o conceito de ponteiro (para não falar em referência) fica mais confuso ainda. Uma variável simples de tipo inteiro ***é*** o valor ou ela ***tem*** o valor? O valor é uma coisa e a variável é outra? Se são diferentes,  o fato de fazer atribuição usando `=` (ou `:=` no bom e velho Pascal) deixa as coisas confusas.

Espero ter perguntado com clareza suficiente para entender a dúvida.

Em tempo: além de esclarecer, como ficariam respondidas cada uma dessas dúvidas no contexto do esclarecimento?

Comment: Caso se interesse ver como a fonte fica depois compilada, tem esse [exemplo simples em C](https://ideone.com/Gj3eY8) que compilado com Clang no formato ELF64 Intel fica [assim](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/7uQlf5f7/0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Variável

Sabendo [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) fica mais fácil dizer que tecnicamente uma variável não é bem o que as pessoas acham que é. Porém para facilitar entendemos que a variável é o que ela dá nome, ou seja, é a caixinha que contém um valor. É uma forma mais coloquial, mas amplamente usada e entendida. A tal ponto que muitas pessoas vão afirmar que isso está absolutamente correto.

A variável desaparece do código porque ela é só o nome para um endereço onde tem um objeto, um valor. O endereço não desaparece. Esse endereço pode ser até mesmo um registrador, se houver otimizações.

A variável é uma indireção, o ponteiro é outra indireção, mas são mecanismos completamente diferentes, a variável é um indireção muito simples, nem chega perto do poder do ponteiro.

Coloquialmente a variável tem um valor. Mais coloquialmente ainda podemos dizer que a variável é o valor.

Estritamente falando o valor está em um objeto que está em uma posição de memória que pode ter um nome ou outra forma simples de chegar ali (um índice por exemplo). Então, colocando outros itens na equação, tudo isso são coisas distintas, principalmente valor e variável.

Pense na indireção, você não está atribuindo um valor para o nome, mas sim para o objeto que ele aponta, ou seja, para o endereço de memória que esse nome de fato se refere.

## Entendendo de outras formas

Quer uma analogia? Você não coloca nada em um domínio de internet. Você coloca em um servidor que tem um endereço IP que pode ser acessado de forma mais fácil e intuitiva por um nome de domínio. É a mesma coisa.

Abre o Excel ou outro software de planilha. Nem todos são iguais, mas acho que o básico todos têm. Isso é uma linguagem de programação. Visual. Acho que assim dá para entender melhor.

Você vê um monte de células. São posições de memória. E possuem endereços que começam com uma ou mais letras e vem algarismo(s) em seguida.

De forma geral podemos falar que há um objeto vazio ali em cada uma delas. O valor pode ser interpretado como alguma coisa mais específica sob certas circunstâncias. Tem um valor ali, mesmo que seja vazio, ele vale algo a ser definido. Também pode ter uma valor mais tradicional.

Muita gente não sabe mas os softwares de planilhas costumam permitir dar nome para cada uma das células. De uma certa forma as células identificadas por seu endereço podem ser consideradas variáveis, porque tem um nome ali, mas igual usamos nas linguagens tradicionais a variável é só o nome dado de forma mais específica.

Então o nome é um *alias*, um apelido, para o endereço da memória (não importa se é o Excel ou C, só a definição de como é a memória é que muda) que contém um objeto e esse objeto possui um valor (pode ter outros atributos, mas esse é o mais importante).

## Conclusão

O importante é entender, não precisa falar estritamente certo. Se todo mundo entende que "a variável vale tanto" é aceitável mesmo que mais tecnicamente não seja correto falar assim.

Variáveis não são só os nomes que estão em uma função. Membros de uma estrutura são variáveis, os elementos de um coleção de dados acessados por alguma forma de índice são variáveis.

Algumas formas de como funciona internamente depende da implementação. É muito raro a especificação da linguagem dizer como deve ser feito. Em C tem um jeito muito comum, mas nada determina como deve ser feito por baixo dos panos, nem precisa existir *stack* e *heap*, e em C  interpretado (sim, isso existe, C não é uma linguagem compilada, as implementações mais conhecidas é que são) pode ser diferente.

O mesmo pode ser dito de linguagens de *script*, inclusive algumas implementações são compiladas/JITtadas e acabam funcionando de forma análoga ao que encontramos em C, isso é detalhe de implementação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os detalhes de implementação (uma mais ou menos tradicional que pudesse ser usada de exemplo) me interessariam,  mas como falou no último parágrafo varia. Ou talvez tenha na pergunta linkada, vou olhar depois.

Answer (score 4):

No caso do C e outras linguagens compiladas, uma variável de função é traduzida pelo compilador para uma posição de memória na pilha. É uma posição relativa, pois um "stack frame" é criado na pilha quando a função é invocada, então as variáveis da função terão endereços.

Se a função for simples e/ou a variável for considerada importante, ela pode ser alocada num registrador da CPU, durante a execução da função.

O ponto é que o nome da variável desaparece, e o resultado final são instruções que guardam ou recuperam o valor em/de uma posição de memória. Se a variável está num registrador, nem isso.

Em linguagens interpretadas tipo Python e Javascript, o equivalente ao "stack frame" da função é uma matriz associativa ou dicionário, e aí realmente o nome da variável é a chave sob a qual o valor é armazenado nesse dicionário.