# O que é valor em computação?

Tags: terminologia, value, arquitetura-computadores, princípios-de-programação, passagem-por-valor

O que é um valor em computação, e, a fim de auxiliar na compreensão e dirimir confusões, qual a sua relação com o conceito mais geral de valor?

Por exemplo, o valor de uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/357).

O valor de uma expressão.

O quanto algo vale vs. o valor em si.

[Passagem por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/357).

Um [objeto-valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232955/357).

Faz sentido falar no valor de um valor?

Quanto vale um valor que está na memória?

O que significa dizer que [uma variável vale alguma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/527528/357)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) define *valor* como sendo "*a representação de alguma entidade que pode ser manipulada por um programa*". É uma definição bem ampla, mas acho que faz sentido que seja assim, já que o conceito parece ser amplo mesmo.

De acordo com esta definição, uma variável pode ser considerada um valor. Afinal, ela representa uma entidade (seja um número, uma string, um objeto qualquer, etc), não? Mas o próprio objeto para o qual a variável aponta, também não seria um valor por si só? Por exemplo:

```java
String s = "abcdefghi";
fazAlgo(s.substring(3, 5));
```

Podemos considerar que a variável `s` representa a *entidade string "abcdefghi"*, e ela pode ser manipulada pelo programa (por exemplo, chamando o método `substring`). Mas a própria string também é uma entidade que pode ser manipulada, sem precisar da variável:

```java
fazAlgo("abcdefghi".substring(3, 5));
```

Então a própria string também seria um valor (de acordo com a definição acima).

Pode-se até argumentar que a variável não é o valor, pois ela só está "apontando" para a string. Mas não podemos também considerar que, ao apontar para algo, ela se torna uma representação deste algo? No caso, `s` não está "representando a string"?

Mais ainda: a variável aponta para o valor, tem o valor, ou ela é o próprio valor? Ou ela é um valor distinto (outra posição da memória, outra "entidade", outra coisa, outra porção de bits) que aponta para outro valor (a string)?

Parece que é uma grande ginástica semântica para que as coisas se encaixem (ou não) em uma definição específica. O que mostra como a definição é ampla e dá margem para diferentes interpretações. Podemos ficar debatendo por horas sem chegar a um consenso (e não parece haver um).

---

## A própria definição mudou ao longo do tempo

Se olharmos o [histórico do artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Value_(computer_science)&action=history), podemos ver que a [primeira versão](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Value_(computer_science)&oldid=1547787) dizia o seguinte:

> *Um valor pode ser um número, string literal, array e qualquer coisa que possa ser tratada como um número. A definição exata varia de acordo com a linguagem de programação. Variáveis e sub-rotinas são geralmente tratados como valores.*

É um pouco mais completa, e ainda inclui o "*qualquer coisa que possa ser tratada como um número*", que pode ser literalmente qualquer coisa (basta pensar que no fim tudo vira um monte de bits, que nada mais é que "um número"). Repare que agora as variáveis são citadas explicitamente, além dos literais (como `42` , `"abc"`, `true`, etc). Mas vale também o destaque para "*varia de acordo com a linguagem*".

Apenas para citar algumas, [Python define assim](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> *Todo objeto tem uma identidade, um tipo e um valor.*
> *...*
> *O valor de alguns objetos pode mudar. Objetos cujo valor pode mudar são chamados de mutáveis; objetos cujo valor não pode mudar depois de criados são chamados imutáveis.*

O segundo parágrafo é interessante, pois em Python temos tuplas, que são objetos imutáveis, e listas, que são objetos mutáveis. Então a tupla `(1, 'abc')` é um valor, assim como a lista `[1, 'abc']`. E os próprios elementos internos (o número `1` e a string `'abc'`) também são valores por si só. Mas ainda fica a dúvida se objetos por si só são valores, ou se eles são entidades que possuem um valor (afinal, eles representam algo que pode ser manipulado pelo programa, o que bateria com a definição atual da Wikipedia; mas a documentação do Python diz que objetos **têm** um valor, e não que eles **são** um).

Só para citar outra linguagem, em Java [há uma seção na especificação da linguagem que trata de "*values*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html). E ali tem as definições de valores que cada tipo pode ter (`int` pode ter valores de -2147483648 a 2147483647, `boolean` só tem os valores `true` e `false`, etc). Destaque para os tipos por referência:

> *An object is a class instance or an array.*
> *The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.*

Ou seja, uma referência a um objeto também é um valor (e consequentemente, uma variável também é?), e vale notar que o `null` também é um valor.

Enfim, cada linguagem vai ter uma definição diferente de valor, mas me parece que todas se encaixam na mais genérica: "algo" (dados/informação/bits/etc) que pode ser manipulado por um programa. O que é esse "algo" pode variar de acordo com a linguagem.

---

Algum tempo depois, em [outra revisão do artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Value_(computer_science)&oldid=363918803), a definição mudou para:

> *Um valor é uma sequência de bits que é interpretada como um tipo de dados. É possível que a mesma sequência de bits tenha valores diferentes, dependendo do tipo usado para interpretar seu significado. Por exemplo, um valor pode ser um inteiro, um float ou uma string.*

Aqui ficou um pouco mais focado nos bits e na forma como eles são interpretados.

Um detalhe que pelo menos para mim não ficou claro é se uma sequência de bits também é um valor por si só, ou se ela só passa a ser um valor depois que é interpretada como um tipo de dados.

Por exemplo, a sequência de bits `00000000000000011111010010101001`. Se eles forem interpretados como um número inteiro, seu valor é `128169`. Se interpretarmos esses mesmos bits como um número de ponto flutante, seu valor é `1.79603E-40`. E se os interpretarmos como um [Unicode code point](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), seu valor é o [caractere *PILE OF POO*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm) (o emoji ).

Mas a sequência de bits em si também é um valor, ou ela passa a ter/ser um valor só depois que é interpretada? Ou o contrário: o valor é somente a sequência de bits, e o `int`, o `float` e o caractere são apenas interpretações diferentes deste valor?

Isso dá a entender que valor é algo que depende do contexto (da forma como ele é interpretado). Ou (se você tem outro entendimento), o valor é uma coisa só, e pode ser interpretado de diferentes formas (a interpretação é diferente, mas o valor é o mesmo - ou ainda, a interpretação pode resultar em um valor diferente).

---

Só para deixar mais confuso, tem [outra revisão](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Value_(computer_science)&oldid=630882687) com mais uma definição diferente:

> *Um valor é uma expressão que não pode ser mais avaliada (uma forma normal)... Por exemplo, a expressão "1 + 2" não é um valor, pois pode ser reduzido à expressão "3". Já esta expressão não pode ser mais reduzida, e portanto é um valor.**
>
> *O valor de uma variável é dado pelo respectivo mapeamento desta no ambiente.*

Aqui já é definido que expressões que não estão na sua forma mais reduzida não são valores ("1 + 2" não é um valor, e sim uma expressão cujo valor é "3"). E também *dá a entender* que uma variável **tem** um valor, mas ela por si só **não é** um (alguns links indicados na pergunta se aprofundam nesta questão). Curioso que isso contradiz (pelo menos da forma que eu entendi) a versão atual do artigo.

E isso que só consultamos uma fonte...

---

#### Outra fonte

No SOen temos [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3300726), que dá outras definições.

Uma das respostas menciona o livro [Types and Programming Languages, de Benjamin C. Pierce](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/tapl/), que define:

> *[...] defines a subset of terms, called values, that are possible final results of evaluation*

Seria algo como pegar todos os termos/resultados possíveis que uma expressão pode ter depois de ser avaliada. Este conjunto de termos possíveis são os valores.

Neste caso, *parece* bater com a definição de que "1 + 2" não é um valor, mas "3" é (pois expressões com números resultam em outro número, então o conjunto de todos os termos possíveis - no caso, os números - inclui o 3, que é um dos valores possíveis). No caso, "1 + 2" seria uma expressão cujo valor é 3. E o "3" seria ambos (é uma expressão cujo valor é ela própria - seria isso o que você quis dizer com "*valor de um valor*"?).

Outra resposta diz:

> *A value is anything representable on a piece of possibly-infinite Turing machine tape.*
>
> *A value is a member of the set of possible interpretations of any possibly-infinite sequence of symbols.*

Ou seja, qualquer coisa que possa ser representada por uma Máquina de Turing seria um valor. Isso me parece mais alinhado com a definição atual da Wikipedia, de que qualquer dado/entidade/informação/sequência de bits que possa ser manipulado por um programa é um valor.

---

#### Quanto aos outros termos

A passagem por valor é somente um mecanismo pelo qual o valor é passado como argumento para uma função (no caso, é passada uma cópia dele). Mas tem um ponto interessante, e vamos usar C como exemplo:

```c
void answerToLife(int *x) {
    *x = 42;
}
```

[C não suporta passagem por referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519731), então o ponteiro é passado por valor. E sabemos que na passagem por valor, a função recebe uma cópia do mesmo. E neste caso, o valor sendo copiado é o ponteiro (no caso, o endereço de memória onde está o `int`). E esse endereço, por sua vez, vai receber outro valor, que é o número `42`.

Então podemos considerar que o ponteiro (o endereço) também é um valor? Acredito que sim, pois no fundo ele também é uma sequência de bits que representa algo e pode ser manipulado pelo programa (um ponteiro é um valor, e ele representa um endereço no qual outro valor se encontra).

E isso flerta com a definição de que um valor depende do contexto e da interpretação referente ao tipo de dado que ele está representando (afinal, um ponteiro também é um monte de bits, e esses bits teriam um valor diferente se fossem interpretados como sendo de outro tipo).

Quanto ao Value Object, não me parece ter relação direta com a definição do termo "valor". A [pergunta linkada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232955/112052) já explica o que é o termo, e não acho necessário repetir aqui.

---

## Conclusão

A definição exata varia conforme o contexto, não há uma única definição canônica e universal. O único ponto que parece ser comum é que o valor é "algo que pode ser manipulado por um programa", mas a definição específica desse algo varia.

O próprio fato da Wikipedia ter mudado tanto a definição mostra que não há consenso. Ou podemos dizer que são as mesmas coisas ditas de formas diferentes (ora mais genérica, ora mais específica), mas ainda sim sempre ficam alguns pontos passíveis de interpretação. E não vou ser eu quem vai dar a palavra final, no fim acho que só expus um pouco mais a <s>confusão</s> pluralidade de definições...

Comment: Muito boa resposta. _"O valor de um valor"_ era sobre o valor (no sentido geral, não-computacional) de um valor (em qualquer sentido).

Comment: @Piovezan Mas pra mim, "*no sentido geral*" e "*em qualquer sentido*" são basicamente a mesma coisa. Ou seja, continuo sem entender :-)

Comment: _"No sentido geral"_ quer dizer no sentido não-computacional, como o valor de uma compra, por exemplo (na verdade, pelo dicionário, há vários sentidos não-computacionais para valor). Talvez faça sentido também falar no valor de um valor computacional. Ou mesmo no valor de um valor não-computacional. É essa a dúvida :)

Comment: Mas é um pouco de malabarismo linguístico, então deixa pra lá. :)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr.

Não há muito segredo sobre o que é um *valor*: uma entidade que possa ser computada pelo computador. Seja ela, em sua forma "humana", um texto, uma imagem, um número, etc.

---

```c
int x = 15;
```

No exemplo acima, temos tokens, mas não vou falar sobre todos eles. O que queremos é `x` e `15`. O primeiro é o identificador de uma variável, e o segundo é o valor da variável. Note que, o texto escrito `15` não é em si o "valor" mas uma representação [literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114473/o-que-%C3%A9-um-literal) do valor.

A grosso modo, até `x` é um valor. Não para o programador, mas para o interpretador. Isso depende da linguagem e da implementação.

Ele foi armazenado na memória, e logo, será computado, calculado ou processado pela máquina. Isso torna o `15` um valor.

Variáveis, ponteiros ou constantes são uma comodidade para você obter os valores definidos anteriormente de forma que você não "os perca".

Valor de um valor é possível desde que "valor" é uma representação abstrata: ele pode ser qualquer coisa (no computador serão apenas bits). Um JSON por exemplo, ele pode ser inteiramente um valor, contendo outros valores dentro dele se você "abrir" ele.

Um número pode gerar um outro valor se você dividir ele por algum outro valor. Confuso não é?

Na ciência da computação, convém dizer que um valor é sempre algo que tenha um tipo de dados. Portanto, qualquer linguagem turing-complete têm valores, e podem ser escritos, lidos ou executados pelo interpretador.